# How to get a list of articles related to a particular category from my other WordPress website?

Tags: database, rss, feed

How to get a list of articles related to a particular category from my other WordPress website. And how do I list that list on another WordPress site?

Comment: You would need to create a restapi endpoint in the site you want the articles from. In your site you will need to create a request, either AJAX or curl, to get the articles from the endpoint. After you got the articles, loop and display them. There are plenty of guides about those subject, not sure anyone would be able to answer your question without extra information

Comment: Thank you. I will Try.

Comment: an RSS widget could do it